# query rasio quantityorder and quantitystock classicmodels

Tags: sql, oracle, mysqli, pentaho, navicat

I want to get the table results for the `quantitystock` field change as the order on the quantity order.

For example on record 1 `quantityorder` is 30 and quantity stock is 7933. I want on record no 2, if the `quantityorder` is 34 then quantity stock = 7933 - 34 so `quantitystock` in record no 2 is 7899. And so on.

What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: explain the problem clearly,unable to understand.

Comment: for example on record 1 quantityorder is 30 and quantity stock is 7933, i want on record no 2, if the quantityorder is 34 then quantity stock = 7933 - 34, quantitystock in record no 2 is 7899. and so on. what the solution?

Comment: For future reference, please **edit your question** to make clarifications or add information. Also, please post data and code as text: not everybody can see images, and more importantly they are hard to work with. Please make it easier for  somebody to provide you with a working solution.

Comment: @triomaulana it will be better you add your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use running sum query to get the previous sum of all order quantity and minus it from quantitystock.

like below for oracle,

select a.*,  (quantitystock  - sum(quantityorder) over (order by ordernumber asc)) as new_quantitystock 
from quantity a